# how to load dynamic database on modal window from dynamic table in php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Hello i want to show dynamic data by using MySQL database base on modal window please give me some demo  for that. I am trying to show dynamic data on table and as i click on button of any record it must show that dynamic data on modal window as well

Answer (score 0):

this is what i have tried

```js
    
<script>
function showHint(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) { 
        document.getElementById("mymodalbody").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("mymodalbody").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "show.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
<script>
  function getPage(id) {
 $('#output').html('<img src="LoaderIcon.gif" />');
 jQuery.ajax({
  url: "get_page.php",
  data:'id='+id,
  type: "POST",
  success:function(data){$('#output').html(data);}
 });
}
</script>
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content" >
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title" style="text-align:center;">Information</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="mymodalbody">
  
    <?php ?>
          
          
  </div>
        
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default " data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->

<div class="container" >
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-12 ">
    
          <table class="table table-bordered " style="text-align:center;">
            <thead >
              <tr style="background-color:#FFF;" >
                <th style="text-align:center;">Sr.</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;">Name</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;">Email</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;">Mobile No</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;">View</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
  <?php
   $i=1;
   $sql=mysql_query("select * from staff order by id asc") or die(mysql_error());
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
   {
  ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['mobile'];?></td>
                <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" onclick="showHint(this.value)" ><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                </td>
              </tr>
  <?php
    $i++;
   }
  ?>
      </tbody>
          </table>
        <!--end green board -->
    </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="pagination" >
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  </ul>`
</div>
```